# Missing files after git pull?

Tags: git, merge, conflict, missing-data

I have a remote that is the same, or similar, to the rails project in my current directory. To sync the two, I do

```
git init
git remote add origin blah@blah
git pull
```

The problem is that some of the files I had in my working copy were added (ie not in the remote), so when I do

```
git status
```

it should show a bunch of untracked files. Instead I see the files from the repo that are out of date.
Why didn't it ask me to resolve conflicts in these files? And where are my old files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The merge implicit in  "git pull" must have overwritten local files that were not committed.

I would suggest this sequence:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m"local"
git remote add origin blah@blah
git fetch origin
```

At this point, observe the repository with "gitk --all"

Merge with

```
git merge remotes/origin/master
```

This should let you know of conflicts, if any. 
And local files won't be overwritten.

Comment: This, I think, is correct. The problem was that those local files were untracked so Git had no way of knowing that they should be kept. git add && git commit are required before you can merge files.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a local repo (with its working directory), you shouldn't need to '`git init`' anything.

```
git remote add origin blah@blah
git pull
```

should be enough.

If you have made a `git init`, that should be in an empty repository, where you then imported the master content of '`origin`'.

---

> I didn't have a local repo, just the local files.

Then you need to add them first (see [r-mercado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/308879/r-mercado)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191747/missing-files-after-git-pull/3191958#3191958)).

From the [`git pull` man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html):

> Warning: Running `git pull` (actually, the underlying `git merge`) with uncommitted changes is discouraged: while possible, it leaves you in a state that is hard to back out of in the case of a conflict.

Comment: I didn't have a local repo, just the local files.

Answer (score 0):

What if, after the commands you did above, you try doing this?

```
git checkout blah
git pull origin blah
```

I'm still learning git, so I'm not positive, but just a guess.  (Might need to replace `blah` with `blah@blah` in the commands above too.)